# clearInterval On Image Slider Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm making an image slider and I'd like to be able to clearInterval() on my autoplay timer from within my init function where I've placed my click event handler for the pagination module. I want to do this so when the user clicks on a dot during autoplay it doesn't break the image rotation. The problem is that the timer functionality is within my play function which is not within my init function. See below:

```
function Plugin( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.item = 0;
    this.init();
}

Plugin.prototype = {

    init: function() {

        var base = this;

        if ( this.options.legend === "on" ) {
            html = "<div id='legend'/>";
            $(this.element).append(this.generateLegend(this.options.images)).find(".img-number").click(function(){

                // store index of currently active image
                base.item = $("#img-container").children(".active").index();

                // only animate if the new index is different from the current
                if ( base.item !== $(this).index() ) {

                    // call animation effect
                    base.move(base.item, $(this).index());

                    // add active class to selected index and remove any previous active classes from other indices
                    base.updateIndex("#legend", $(this).index());
                    base.updateIndex("#img-container", $(this).index());

                }

            }).wrapAll(html);
        if ( this.options.autoplay === "on" ) {
            base.play();
        }

        return this;

    },

    updateIndex: function(el, index) {
        $(el).children().eq(index).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    },

    play: function() {

        var base = this;

        setInterval(function() {

            if ( base.item === base.options.images.length-1 ) {
                base.updateIndex("#img-container", 0);
                base.updateIndex("#legend", 0);
                base.move(base.item, 0);
                base.item = 0;
            }
            else {
                base.updateIndex("#img-container", base.item+1);
                base.updateIndex("#legend", base.item+1);
                base.move(base.item, base.item+1);
                base.item += 1;
            }

        }, base.options.pduration);

    },

    // animation effect for changing image indices
    move: function(cur, dest) {
        $("#img-container > img").animate({
            "right": "+=" + 100 * (dest-cur) + "%"
        }, this.options.aduration, this.options.easing);
    }

};
```

I'm trying to write this plugin without "cheating" by looking at how other sliders do it. I want to do it my way, but also properly.

Comment: "Cheating" is the best way to learn!

Comment: Looking at existing code == cheating, letting others solve the issue != cheating?

Comment: The problem is I'll see other functionality that I may want to write myself at a later point. I just want help with this one particular problem.

Comment: No. 70% of what you learn is through reading, 30% is through writing your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the interval in the `base` var: `this.intervalTimer = window.setInterval( ... );` and access it where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` both return an integer which can be used with `clearTimeout()` and `clearInterval()`, which is used to cancel intervals/timeouts.

Saved the returned integer in your object instance and cancel the interval/timeout when user interaction is detected.